# how to use ruby's mongo driver to update a mult-level document

Tags: ruby, mongodb, driver

How do I use the ruby's mongo driver to update a multi-level document.  For example, here's part of the docuement:

```
...
"group_overrides": [
  {
    "additional_filesystem_gb": 0,
    "components": [
      {
        "comp": "jbosseap-6",
        "cart": "jbosseap-6",
        "cart_id": ObjectId("5423d363f4b25eea0b000021")
      }
    ],
    "max_gears": 1
  }
],
```

In the mongo-shell I can do something like:

```
db.applications.update({name:"ulmuqhfv"}, {$set: {"group_overrides.0.additional_filesystem_gb": 1}})
```

and the document will be updated.  When I tried the following:

```
db.update('applications', {"app_name"=>"ulmuqhfv"}, {"$set"=>{"group_overrides.0.additional_filesystem_gb"=>1})
```

It failed.  What's the correct syntax for updating an array?

db is an instance of a wrapper class around the ruby mongo driver.  Here's what the update method looks like:

```
def update(c_name, selector, opts)
  db = @db.collection(c_name)
  if opts
    db.update(selector, opts).to_a
  else
    db.update(selector).to_a
  end
end
```

Comment: What is `db` in Ruby? What specifically does "it failed" mean?

Comment: db is just a wrapper, it basically, does a access to the collection and calls the update()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as simple as that:

```
db['applications'].update({"app_name"=>"ulmuqhfv"}, {"$set"=>{"group_overrides.0.additional_filesystem_gb"=>1})
```

you need to access your collection as you access hash keys, `db['applications']` will return the collection object

```
mongo_connection = Mongo::Connection.new("localhost", 27017) # your connection settings
db = mongo_connection.db("mydb") # select database
coll = db['applications'] # select collection
coll.update({"app_name"=>"ulmuqhfv"}, {"$set"=>{"group_overrides.0.additional_filesystem_gb"=>1})
```

you can learn more [here](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.1.5/file.TUTORIAL.html) under ***Getting a Collection*** section

Comment: my db class does the collection select already.  I ultimately call, the collection.update() just like your answer does.  Please note the selector & opt hash in my example is the same as what you have suggested...

Comment: not according to the code you posted. please post your code inside your db class, and try to use it directly to be more clear

Comment: def update(c_name, selector, opts)
      db = @db.collection(c_name)
      if opts
        db.update(selector, opts).to_a
      else
        db.update(selector).to_a
      end
    end

Comment: as i said, try to use the driver directly and write the result

Comment: Your approach and mine have the same result.  {"updatedExisting"=>false, "n"=>0, "lastOp"=>seconds: 0, increment: 0, "connectionId"=>66, "err"=>nil, "ok"=>1.0}... but the document is not updated.

Comment: you sure u use the same update index? i see u use `name` in the first code and `app_name` in the second

Comment: Ah...stupid me...that was it...  thanks for finding my dumb mistake.